# How does Web API respond without being hosted?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I was following the Microsoft tutorial on Web API 2 here
[Web API 2 tutorial](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api).

I was trying to run it and was getting a 403.14 error. After some research I found out that you just have to build it and call its functions from a browser as stated here:
[Answer to Dealing with 403.14 error](https://forums.asp.net/t/1961303.aspx?HTTP%20Error%20403%2014%20Forbidden%20).

I was under the impression a Web API needs to be hosted in order to be called upon, if I'm not running it, how is the browser able to call its functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new Web API project, Visual Studio will create a new ASP.NET application and add the Web API specific templates. An ASP.NET application can be hosted in Visual Studio's built-in development server (also known as IIS Express). So when you hit <kbd>F5</kbd> you are basically starting this websever which will host the application and it will listen on some port number.

You can see the running developer server icon in Windows tasks bar:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't build on F5, that's the thing, but if you build it, for some reason yes IIS hosts it without it running.

Comment: So in this case maybe it is hosted in IIS and not IIS Express. Look at the project settings - Web tab which will contain the hosting properties.

Comment: It's using IIS Express. I'm just wondering why when I'm not running the application though I can still call its functions.

Comment: If you hit F5 once, it will launch the webserver. Then you no longer need to be hitting F5 for it to work. Only recompile locally and IIS Express picks up the changes you have made. If you close Visual Studio and reopen the project there will be no IIS Express running and listening for your application. Just look for its icon in the windows taskbar.

Comment: oh so once you run at least once, regardless that you stop it, it will continue to be hosted?

Comment: Yes, IIS Express continues to run in the background. So just recompile the project in Visual Studio and your changes will be picked up immediately in the browser. It's quite handy when developing.

Comment: Wow OK didn't know that tysm!

Answer (score 0):

Web API needs to be hosted and it is hosted in IIS Express, as Darin already said, the moment you run the *ProductsApp* project. You can read more about IISExpress here [1].

However, your issue comes from the fact that once you run the project, the browser opens the default path (http://localhost:47503/ in may case, with a different port on your machine), which is not mapped.

What you have to do is: run the application in Visual Studio, but then add to that default path that opens in the browser an actual path that exists in the project (e.g: /api/products). So your resulting URL will be something like: http://localhost:47503/api/products. This was also stated in the example you mentioned [2], but maybe it was not clear enough.

[1] https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview

[2] https://forums.asp.net/t/1961303.aspx?HTTP%20Error%20403%2014%20Forbidden%20

Comment: It does return a json file, however why if I'm not running the application, I can still call its functions which was my main question.